# Recovery of password from unsaved TXT file or clipboard text

Tags: passwords, clipboard

One week ago I have used (https://passwordsgenerator.net/) page to create a strong password. After this, I wanted to backup this unique password to .TXT file but never saved it. Needless to say I do not have mentioned password.

Here is what I have tried so far:

1. I have attempted to search for unsaved/lost file with various tools without luck. Windows should have this somewhere, but have no idea or enough knowledge to to find it
2. I looked up in browsing history/cookies for missing password - also without luck

Some facts:

- I have exact time and date when password was generated
- PC was never restarted after that
- I know the name of the file in which one password has been copied, but it was never saved
- Password is used for a crypto currency wallet. Recovery in any other way is impossible.

Comment: I believe, the only place you will find this string is in the memory of the Chrome process.  I assume the Notepad process has gone?.  Do you know if Chrome.exe has been restarted since?  If you're not sure maybe you can check the uptime of the Chrome.exe process and correlate with the time you know by using a tool such as Process Explorer. https://docs.microsoft.com/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer.  As an example, I can use that site to gen a pass, attach to the Chrome process, navigate a number of times away from the page and still be able to find the password string in memory.

Comment: Well Chrome process was killed several times in between. I have attempted to repeat what you wrote but no success. Can you give please a bit more details about how to find it in memory? I am lacking some technical knowledge here. Is is futile, if chromes process has been killed in between?

Comment: What program did you copy the password to? Notepad? Your question doesn't say.

Comment: Yes, it was notepad.I copied it in, but never pressed save.

Comment: To just prove that the password could be retrieved from the memory of the Chrome.exe process after navigation I used Windbg to attach to the Chrome process and just used the PDE Windbg extension (Andrew Richards - Microsoft) to search for the string of the newly generated password using the command `!pde.ssz [genpassword]` which it did find. This alone proves it is retrievable under certain circumstanced. That said, If the Chrome.exe process has been killed then the memory of Chrome doesn't seem to be an option. If Notepad.exe has gone also, then I don't see any other option.

Comment: I understand. Any ideas perhaps how and if possible this could be restored our of Chrome's cookies or cache? I have attempted several things already but I am basically trying things. Do not have sufficient in-depth knowledge where to look, how to look etc.

Comment: Sadly it's not stored in a cookie or in the cache.  You can open the Chrome cache by going to the URL `chrome://cache/`.  You may then be able to still search for and find the URL which will take you to:
`chrome://view-http-cache/https://passwordsgenerator.net/` This will display the HTML of the page but as the password string is dynamically generated by the client size Javascript it's not stored in the cache. Sorry.